# How to save and edit a file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I want a user of my website to enter some text in a text area and when he submits the form, the text that he entered be stored in a .txt file that is present in same directory of the current web page? I don't have a slight idea how it's done or even if it could be done in JavaScript.

#### How can it be done?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have access to the file system like that (in some cases it does). You should be using the serverside to save files etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can, HTML5 File API has a `saveAs` API that can be used to save binary data using Javascript. You can generate a .txt file by first getting the data into a canvas and saving it as:

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  saveAs(blob, filename);
});
```

See this demo, the text file is actually generated in browser without PHP. 
http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

There is an excellent article written back in 2011 by Eli Grey on html5rocks:  http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

More reading at W3C: [Filesaver interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#the-filesaver-interface)

---

**Edit 2016 Update**

My original answer showed an example using the BlobBuilder interface which has since been [deprecated and marked as obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder). It is now recommended to use the [Blob Construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to manipulate binary data.

At the time of posting, Blob construct is [supported on all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=blob). IE 11, Edge 13, Firefox 43, Chrome 45, Safari 9, Opera 35, iOS Safari 8.4, Android Chrome 49.

Demo:

- Koldev has posted jsfiddle how to use this new construct to save a json file.
- Link: https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/

More reading:

- [MDN Blob Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)
- [Caniuse Blob construction](http://caniuse.com/#search=blob)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not do what the original poster requested. They wanted a file that could be updated and saved to the server, not a file that could be downloaded on the client-side.

Answer (score 4):

you cant save file with js in server nor the client system.
you need a server side script like php or asp.net to save files to server. but cant save anything other than a cookie to the client system.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You need some server-side script to access the filesystem of the server such as PHP or Java.

Answer (score 4):

This one might help you.

<s>http://wcetdesigns.com/tutorials/2012/11/01/edit-save-file.html</s>
https://web.archive.org/web/20131210151034/http://wcetdesigns.com/tutorials/2012/11/01/edit-save-file.html

```
edit.php, file where users can edit using the textarea tag.
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://wcetdesigns.com/assets/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function save(){
     var x = $("textarea").val();
     var data = 'c='+x;

     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'save.php',
         data: data,
         success: function(e){
             $("#s").html(e);
         }
     });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea>
<?php

$fn = "blank.html"; //FILE TO BE EDITED (FILENAME EDITABLE)
$file = fopen($fn, "r+"); //OPENS IT
$fr = fread($file, 1000000); //READS IT
fclose($file); //CLOSE CONNECTIONS
echo $fr; //SHOWS THE EDITABLE FILE HERE

?>
</textarea><br>
<input onClick="save()" id="x" type="button" value="Save"><br><br>
<span id="s"></span><br>
<a href="blank.html" target="_new">view file</a>
</body>
</html>
save.php, file where the saving process will take place.
<?php

$c = $_POST["c"]; //TEXT FROM THE FIELD

$f = 'blank.html'; //FILE TO SAVE (FILENAME EDITABLE)
$o = fopen($f, 'w+'); //OPENS IT
$w = fwrite($o, $c); //SAVES FILES HERE
$r = fread($o, 100000); //READS HERE
fclose($o); //CLOSES AFTER IT SAVES

//DISPLAYS THE RESULTS
if($w){
    echo 'File saved';
} else {
    echo 'Error saving file';
}

?>
```

Javascript doesn't have access to file system so you must use some server side language like PHP as in the given example

Answer (score 3):

You can send that particular textarea value through ajax by javascript. Then on the server side you can put a code, where you can accept the string and save it in a text file. You cant just do it with Javascript, you need a serverside code..

```
        //Html
    <textarea id="TextArea"></textarea>

    //javascript
    var dataVal = $('#TextArea').val();
    if(dataVal!="")
    {
    $.ajax({
                url: '/createTextFile',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: dataVal,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('Success');      
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('Error: There was some error while posting. Please try again later.');
                }
            });
    }

    //You can server side code (C#)

    function SaveToTextFIle(text)
    {
        try
        {
            // The using statement automatically closes the stream and calls  
            // IDisposable.Dispose on the stream object. 
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```