# How to store and get data from a json file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, xml

I would like to create a little kind of CMS. For that I want to code a function, which automatically creates a list of the files, which were created with the CMS. This list sould be display in a html file and styled with CSS. For that I want to create a json-File, in which i store the title and the location of the new file.
Then it should look like this:

```
{
  "new_sites":
  {
    "title": "source",
    "otherTitle": "otherSource"
  }
}
```

Now I want to know, how I can get (or store new) data from the json-File and use it as variables in javascript so that I can display it on the html page.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer, you need to start by [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Comment: Maybe this post might be of some use? [**How to save and edit a file using javascript**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087881/how-to-save-and-edit-a-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Given these three variables:

```
var myNewSite = 'newSite';
var myNewTitle = 'newTitle';
var myNewSource = 'newSource';
```

and your final json variable initialized in this way:

```
var myJson = {};
```

You could simply:

```
myJson[myNewSite] = {
    myNewTitle: myNewSource
};
```

Comment: I don't see how this is of any help.... this doesn't explain how to **get** the data or how to **save** it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery api to get data from json-file.Suppose you have a data.json file in directory.

```
<script>
  var container={};
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { 
    container=data;
  }); 
</script>
```